# Batch, variable inside variable in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop, cmd

How to set a variable inside a variable in a for loop? When I execute this code the var[] is empty. Someone can help me?

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var[0]=aaa
set var[1]=bbb
set var[2]=ccc
set var[3]=ddd
set var[4]=eee

for /L %%g in (1,1,3) do (
set /a num=!RANDOM! %% 5
echo position: !num!
echo keyword: !var[%num%]! :: THIS LINE NOT WORKING
)

pause
```

Comment: Give this a try: `call echo keyword: %%var[!num!]%%`

Comment: Thanks Squashman. This works.

Comment: This management is fully explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have two options to get the double variable expansion you require. You can either use `CALL` or another `FOR` command.

```
call echo keyword: %%var[!num!]%%
```

or

```
FOR %%h in (!num!) do echo keyword: !var[%%h]!
```